# Stain on bathroom tiles

Tags: tile, cleaning, ceramic-tile

[image]

It seems a bit of excess cement or grout have mixed with water and stained my bathroom tiles. Tried soaking it / rubbing it with cleaning vinegar but to no avail.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Use a commercial grout cleaning product or a 50/50 mixture of white vinegar and water.  Spray the solution and let it sit for a few minutes then scrub with a sponge or brush.  Repeat until the stains are removed.  It may take multiple tries.